# YAML Like templating language for HTML?

Tags: html, templates, yaml

I remember seeing a "minimalistic" or "simple" markup language that expanded directly to html. It had some resemblance to YAML, e.g.

```
h1: Hi there!
ul:
  li: item 1
  li: item 2
```

Does anyone know of a templating language like this? **NOTE:** It isn't markdown or wiki creole, it was something that had direct correspondence to HTML tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're thinking of [Haml](http://haml-lang.com/).